# Efficient way to update profile picture with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the one below to store images. When an image is an active profile image, then profile is set to 1. But then I need to set the rest to be 0 so that only one image is with profile = 1, while the rest is 0.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS image;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS image (
    id              INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    width           INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    height          INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    extension       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    created         INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    user_id         INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    profile         INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    deleted         INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE image ADD INDEX (user_id);
```

Is there an efficient way for me to achieve this? Or do I need to do 2 queries and first set all images to profile = 0 that belongs to a certain user, and then set the specific Image to profile = 1 with that specific id?

```
UPDATE image SET profile = 0 WHERE user_id = 1;
UPDATE image SET profile = 1 WHERE id = 9;
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: That's the way I'd do it.

Comment: you can add a profile-image-id in your user table and keep only the one selected as activate profile image in the table. you can have as many profile images as you want, but you can only have one active, per user

Comment: I'd go with the foreign key approach as well. Make the user record point to the image record rather than rely on maintaining "active" state of all images. Faster and more reliable to update/reference image id column on user.